How to detect there is no data or no stream. Rx.net
I want to managed case in rx.net where there is no data or no stream. I just what to simulate is there connection with udp service.
I am trying to do that such like this:

Observable
.Defer(
    () => _udpDataService.GetUdpClient()
    .ReceiveAsync()
    .ToObservable()
    .Retry()
    .Catch((Exception ex) =>
    {
        return Observable.Empty<UdpReceiveResult>();
    })
)
.Repeat()
.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
.RetryWhen(error =>
    error.Do(ex =>
    {
        IsConnected = false;
    })
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
)
.Subscribe(_ => {
    Console.WriteLine("LISTEN");
    IsConnected = true;
});


It only works well when there is no data for a short time. What I mean is that when I turn the service off, the app responds and sets IsConnected to false, and when I turn the service on after <10 seconds, IsConnected is immediately set to true. But if I turn off the service and turn it on after 5 minutes, the stream takes about a few seconds (sometimes it is 30 seconds, sometimes 60 seconds) to listen again.
How can I achieve this? Maybe some way without using timeout?

I think I've solved my problem. I remove timeout and retryWhen from my observable and create separate variable monitor to detect is any data from stream.
Observable
.Defer(
    () => _udpDataService.GetUdpClient()
    .ReceiveAsync()
    .ToObservable()
    .Retry()
    .Catch((Exception ex) =>
    {
        return Observable.Empty<UdpReceiveResult>();
    })
)
.Repeat()
.Subscribe(_ => {
    Console.WriteLine("LISTEN");
    IsConnected = true;
});

_monitorIsConnected = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Timestamp()
    .Select(_ => DateTimeOffset.Now)
    .CombineLatest(_functionPlc.CreateListener<UdpReceiveResult>()!.GetStream().Timestamp(), (now, last) => now - last.Timestamp)
    .Where(diff => diff > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
    .Subscribe(_ =>
    {
        IsConnected  = false;
    });

